# ReactJS: Tailwind override global CSS inline

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this rails reactjs app that if I put this line in the form

```
<input type='submit'/>
```

It will create for me a blue button.  I have just installed Tailwind and if I input this line with tailwind class, it does not have any effect on the button design.

```
<input type='submit'
              className='bg-red-500  text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full'/>
```

Is there a way that I can override this global settings like putting !important inline in the className?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a ! character before the class name and that should do the job

Example:

```
<input type='submit'
             className='!bg-red-500  text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full'/>
```

Docs: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#built-in-important-modifier

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can config `tailwind.config.js` if you add this

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

this will generate all `tailwind` classes as `!important`

read more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important)